# Classification in BERT - why not use class as a feature?

Tags: natural-language, transformers, language-models

I am currently following [this post](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/), which details how BERT was trained. I had a few questions about the classification task:

1. In the post, it mentions that the authors of BERT decided to add classification into the language modeling in the following way:
   [image]
   However, is there a reason why the authors did it this way? Why not use the classification class as a feature and not a label?
2. In general, when training in this multi-task way, when is it better to add the multi-task as a feature or as a label?

Comment: How do you propose including it as a feature then performing classification? It seems circular to predict X from X, no? Besides, you're not always using BERT for next-sentence prediction. You don't want to _always_ have to provide it with a "is the next sentence" feature, when there isn't always a next sentence to model!

Comment: I am not proposing to predict X, I am proposing to use X in place of the [CLS] token itself. But thinking about this some more, I suppose that if the actual goal is to do classification, we won't actually have X.

But then I'm wondering: why do we use a single token output to do classification? Why not use all the BERT-generated embeddings for all tokens, as opposed to the output of just the [CLS] token?

Comment: Good insight. Your follow-up question is a good one but ought to be a separate post—comments aren’t intended for ongoing discussion.

Comment: Your insight is the solution: the CLS output token is used later for classification, but not at this stage. Technically, you could make a classification output instead of the CLS token. I guess they wanted to learn some valuable latent representation there ...